# How to delete or remove the tooltip from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an icon in javascript with tooltip.

```
var icon = '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="icon-ok" data-type="reftooltip" title="Save" style="cursor: pointer"></a>';
```

this icon is displayed and removed dynamically. When I am removing this icon dynamically from javascript by using below code:

```
success: function(){
//other code//
saveparents.parent().parent().find('a.icon-ok').remove();
//other code//
}
```

icon is getting removed but tooltip "Save" is still displayed on UI. When I refresh the page, it disappears. But I want it to remove as soon as icon-ok gets removed.

Also I debugged in firebug and found that a div class for tooltip is being created in html page

```
<html><body>
<div ...................>... </div> 
<div class="tooltip fade top in" style="top: 156.5px; left: 256.667px; display: block;">
   <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
   <div class="tooltip-inner">Save</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

From firebug I can remove this div by right clicking on deletenode. It successfully removes from UI as well. So I think if I do this using javascript code, it should be removed.

But I don't know what code to put in success function to delete that div class tooltip fade top in. I need help here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably have to remove tha actual tooltip as well:

`$('body>.tooltip').remove();`

Or even better, use your tooltip's native remove function.

Answer (score 5):

The `title` attribute becomes the tool-tip text in **some** browsers. Remove that (either directly, or using Javascript) and it should go away.

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H33.html

> Some graphical user agents will display a tool tip when the mouse
>   hovers above an anchor element containing a title attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's worth to try:

```
success: function(){
 //other code//
   ('a.icon-ok').removeAttr("title");
 //other code//
}
```

**EDIT:**

I read again your question:

> But I don't know what code to put in success function to delete that div class tooltip fade top in. I need help here.

try this way:

```
success: function(){
 //other code//
   ('div').removeClass("tooltip fade top in"); //<-- costumize your selector
 //other code//
}
```

good luck !!

Comment: @Charlie: it still didnt work.. but i got the solution.. thanks :)

Comment: Congrats ! . why dont you just create an answer? maybe useful for others. :)

Comment: works when removing "title" as well as "data-original-title" attributes

Answer (score 2):

I've tried all these answer, but what worked for me is this,

```
$("#id").tooltip( "destroy" );
```

Or you can also use

```
$("#id").tooltip( "close" );
```

But, I prefer the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your valuable inputs!!
I added this line in success() function and it worked

> `$("[class='tooltip fade top in']").remove();`